# Python flask-cors ImportError: No module named 'flask-cors' Raspberry pi

Tags: python, flask, raspberry-pi, flask-cors

I'm following the flask-cors tutorial from the documentation here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Cors

but when i installed it on my raspberry pi and run my python app i'm getting this error

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
ImportError: No module named 'flask_cors'`

here is my python script:

```
from flask import Flask
from Main import main
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin    
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
main = main() 

@app.route('/turn' ,methods=['GET', 'OPTIONS'])
def index():
  return main.turn()

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: `$ pip install -U flask-cors` and check that it installs in the correct directory

Comment: i already did that is not working

Comment: i mean, it says is already installed but is not working

Comment: if you `print(sys.path)`, you have to ensure that `flask_cors` is inside one of those printed directories.

Comment: NameError: name 'sys' is not defined

Comment: you have to `import sys`

Comment: what should i do if is not in any of those printed directories? this is what i got `['/home/pi/Downloads/tesis', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-arm-linux-gnueabihf', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']`

Comment: If its not in there, then you need to find the package you installed with pip and move it to one of those directories. To prevent this, you can change your pip settings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you `import sys` and `print(sys.path)`, this will show you where your available packages are installed.

In the event that pip installed `flask_cors` outside of one of these directories, you should move the file to one of the directories or you can `sys.path.append(<your path to flask_cors>)`.

To prevent pip from installing into a bad directory, I would recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650196/4225229)

Comment: So yeah basically the problem in raspberry pi is that when you're installing a package with pip there's a difference with pip for python 2 and pip3 for python 3. So the easiest way to install flask-cors on the raspberry for python 3 is with `pip3 install -U flask-cors` and not `pip install -U flask-cors`. it's working perfect now.

Answer (score 16):

It worked for me finally

```
pip install -U flask-cors
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue where after installing flask_cors it was still giving me a ModuleNotFoundError. Try this:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall flask_cors
sudo pip3 install Flask-Cors
```

It's a subtle difference but it worked for me. Even though flask_cors appears to install a package and it's written that way in python when actually importing it, the actual package name installed with pip is Flask-Cors.

Comment: Running with pip3 worked for me also. I'm on Window 10 with both python 2 & 3 installed

Answer (score 2):

I spent a day trying to resolve this. Here are my steps:
First i closed my VSCODE and open it again, then run

```
pip uninstall flask
pip uninstall flask_cors
pip3 install flask
pipenv shell
pipenv install flask_cors
pip install pipreqs
git add .
git commit -am "New cor resolved"
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 2):

When my virtual environment was running I installed flask-cors and I got the same error. Then I deactivated the virtual environment and run the command:

```
pip install -U flask-cors
```

Answer (score 1):

Following command working in my case. Change python version according to your system.

```
python3.7 -m pip install flask
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you encounter this trouble in Conda env, ap per conda documentation, use-

```
conda install -c conda-forge flask_cors
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pipenv, you might just need to turn on your virtual environment too by typing:

```
pipenv shell
```

while in your root directory (with the pipfile.lock file in it).

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo pip3 install flask-cors
```

close PyCharm and reopen your project.

Comment: Using `sudo` with `pip install` is almost always a bad idea. Don't mix PyPI packages with system packages.

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Answer (score -3):

If you are running your python script as sudo, then...

```
sudo pip install -U flask-cors
```