# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, import, module

I cannot use any library because I always get this error

I installed modules several times still doesnt work

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask.ext.bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

debug = True
app = Flask(__name__)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
cors = CORS(app)

app.config['MYSQL_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_USER'] = 'root'
app.config['MYSQL_PASSWORD'] = ''
app.config['MYSQL_DB'] = ''

mysql = MySQL(app)

@app.route('/register', methods=['POST'])
def register():
    print(request)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/_____/_____/_______/________/server/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    **import**(module_name)
  File "_____/_____/_______/________/server/app.py", line 2, in 
    from flask_cors import CORS
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_cors'

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714769/python-flask-cors-importerror-no-module-named-flask-cors-raspberry-pi Or you could try pip install flask-cors --upgrade

Comment: Have you tried to install flask-cors with pip?

Comment: Yes i tried to install it several times

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have used pip to install flask-cors but looks like you are using python3. So you need to use pip3, in my opinion.

```sh
pip3 install -U flask-cors
```

If you have already tried pip3 then I have underestimated your problem. Apologies.