# ImportError: No module named 'flask_cors'

Tags: python, flask, visual-studio-code

I have installed flask_cors like so:
pip install Flask-Cors
pip3 install -U flask-cors,
pip install -U flask-cors
pip install flask-cors --upgrade

This is my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

any answer to solve this error is appreciated

[image]
Thankyou

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python flask-cors ImportError: No module named 'flask-cors' Raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714769/python-flask-cors-importerror-no-module-named-flask-cors-raspberry-pi)

Comment: i used each and every command mentioned over there still the error persists.@Prophet

Comment: Did you use any virtual environment? Check if the module is installed in your current used python interpreter.

Comment: Please let me  know how can i check it.? @MollyWang-MSFT

Comment: Run `pip show module_name` in integrated Terminal and see if its location is `your current python interpreter\lib\site-packages`. You may edit and upload this screenshot in your question.

Comment: Please check it,
```
Name: Flask-Cors
Version: 3.0.3
Summary: A Flask extension adding a decorator for CORS support
Home-page: https://github.com/corydolphin/flask-cors
Author: Cory Dolphin
Author-email: corydolphin@gmail.com
License: MIT
Location: c:\users\akhil\python\python39\lib\site-packages
Requires: Flask, Six
Required-by:
PS C:\Users\AKHIL\Downloads\2_automation (1)\2_automation>
```
@Molly Wang-MSFT

Comment: Please check my answer and if there's anything missed or you want to know, please comment there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**The first case:**

Install the module in not current used python interpreter. Use `pip show flask_cors` to check if its location is `your current python interpreter\lib\site-packages.` If not, after selecting python interpreter, open a new integrated Terminal then use command to reinstall modules.

**The second case:**

You've installed the module successfully in current used python environment, then import module in code, but Pylance still throws the error
`ImportError: No module named 'flask_cors'<ReportMissingImports>`. What you need to do is opening Command Palette and choose **Reload Window**, the error should go away.

Please have a try.
[image]

Comment: Please check my image once i have uploaded it, and let me know what changes can i make on it.
Your support is Very Much Apprecated. @Molly Wang-MSFT

Comment: @AkhilSeeramsetty. Press `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open Command Palette and choose **Python: Select interpreter**, if the current path shown in box is `C:\users\akhil\python\python39\python.exe`, then `flask_cors` is installed correctly in your selected environment. You need to save your files then reload window.

Comment: @AkhilSeeramsetty. You're welcome. Happy Coding:)

Comment: Thanks! This got me in the right area.  For me I needed to select my Python 3.9.9 64-bit Interpreter located C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python3.9_3.9.25544.0_x64_...  which is NOT the recommended one.

Comment: @NewtonEntropy. Glad your question has been solved :)

Comment: I have a similar problem when running in a bash shell. I got the same error. My problem is solved by opening a new terminal with fresh activation of the venv environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running flask from a conda environment, install flask_cors with conda:

```
conda install flask_cors
```