# I have a trouble with install flask_cors by pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, pip, flask-cors

```
AJackTis-MacBook-Air:API ajackti$ pip install flask_cors
```

> DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st,
>   2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python
>   2.7.
>
> Requirement already satisfied: flask_cors in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (3.0.7)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: Six in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask_cors) (1.12.0)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: Flask>=0.9 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from flask_cors) (1.0.2)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.14 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.9->flask_cors)
>   (0.15.2)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.9->flask_cors)
>   (7.0)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.9->flask_cors)
>   (2.10)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask>=0.9->flask_cors)
>   (0.24)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in
>   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from
>   Jinja2>=2.10->Flask>=0.9->flask_cors) (0.23)

Although, I have installed library flask_cors. But when I import it, it was an error.

```
AJackTis-MacBook-Air:API ajackti$ python

>>> from flask_cors import CORS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named flask_cors
```

I hope I find a solution to fix it. Thanks for helping me

Comment: I suggest a checklist after that we can help you more:
1- can you check `pip list` and see if the flask_cors  is there?
2- And make sure that your python refers to python2.7, not another version of python.
3- make sure that you are not in a virtual environment;

Comment: yeah. Flask-Cors in this list. but I can't use this. Do you have any solution for this? @Mehdi

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using python 2.7(maybe there is another installation of python on your computer, and you are not in a`virtual environment`. use `python --version` for the first one.

Comment: for checking if you are using `venv` take a look at this:https://stackoverflow.com/a/1883251/2754195

Comment: if you are sure about where your python code is running.
please run this command `pip install flask-cors --upgrade` or `pip install -U flask-cors`

Comment: I use python to code anything. I don't want to use venv to run code.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you use venv to run your code, I'm trying to troubleshoot your problem.  BTW what about `pip install flask-cors --upgrade or pip install -U flask-cors`

Comment: and pip which i am using is of python2.7. When running your command(pip install flask-cors --upgrade or pip install -U flask-cors) It is still an error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python flask-cors ImportError: No module named 'flask-cors' Raspberry pi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48714769/python-flask-cors-importerror-no-module-named-flask-cors-raspberry-pi)

Comment: take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48715014/2754195

Comment: Yes. I have a list of sys.path. And now Will I do next? Hope your help :(

Comment: take a look at the path and check if flask-cors exist there or not.

Comment: It doesn't have in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

Comment: Can I install it in this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Hack

One hack for you is to add the installation path to your python path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
\\ your code
```

## Solution

as said in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41650196/2754195) you can change the path of installation temporary and permanently
example: 
`pip install flask-cors --target  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: OK. This is a solution for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you are using other version of Python, you should change it in the command. For example: if you use `python 3.6` the command would be `pip install flask-cors --target  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages`