# Pip3 install into the incorrect folder

Tags: python-3.x, macos, path, pip, environment-variables

When I `pip3 install <package>`, it'll install and then it will not load properly. I looked around the internet and saw that it's a path issue.

```
Jacky-Lam-MacBook-Pro:~ jackylam$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
Jacky-Lam-MacBook-Pro:~ jackylam$ which pip3
/usr/local/bin/pip3
Jacky-Lam-MacBook-Pro:~ jackylam$ pip3 --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
Jacky-Lam-MacBook-Pro:~ jackylam$ ECHO $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
Jacky-Lam-MacBook-Pro:~ jackylam$ pip3 install JayDeBeapi
Requirement already satisfied: JayDeBeapi in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: JPype1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from JayDeBeapi) (0.7.1)
```

I tried this:
[How to change pip installation path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650158/how-to-change-pip-installation-path)
But it did not seem to work.

How do I reconfigure my pip3 path to match the path my python is running?

Comment: `pip` installs into the correct directory, there is nothing to reconfigure. What is your problem with `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`?

Comment: @phd When I attempt to import packages, I don't think it's referencing that folder. 
`Jacky-Lam-MacBook-Pro:~ jackylam$ python3 -m pip --version
pip 19.3.1 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)` This command reveals I am using a different version of pip. How do I change that?

Comment: Just continue using `python3 -m pip`: `python3 -m pip install JayDeBeapi`

Comment: That worked, but would I run into any errors otherwise?

Comment: I tried installing a package using `python3 -m pip install` and got this .
`WARNING: The script django-admin is installed in '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin' which is not on PATH.`

Comment: Add `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin` to `PATH`. Or install into `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages` and add `/usr/local/bin` to `PATH`.