# Once a Python upgraded to a new version how do you change the path where to Pip install installs?

Tags: python, pip, pyenv

I've installed a newer version of Python under wsl2 using:

pyenv install 3.9.6
pyenv global 3.9.6

Before I was using 3.8

When I pip install it still looks in the previous pip path related to Python 3.8.5. for already installed packages:

/home/ludo915/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages

How do I update the path to where pip install installs packages and what exactly am I supposed to set it to?

Ludo

Comment: Modify your new version so you can see a path as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I update the path to where pip install installs packages

Is the wrong question. There should be one installation of pip for each python installation that you have. Invoking the correct `pip` for the corresponding `python` version will automatically install to the correct `site-packages` directory.

I am not too familiar with pyenv, but a fail proof advice is to invoke `pip` using your python interpreter like

```
python -m pip install
```

You can replace `python` with the interpreter that you want to use specifically. If `python --version` already shows that it points to 3.9, then you should be good to go. Otherwise, you might need to do `python3.9 -m pip install`

Answer (score -1):

You can either install it using the below command :

> python3.9 -m pip install **package-name**
> which will be integrated with python3.9

or

If you want to modify the existing default path, then please refer to the below link.

[How to change pip installation path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650158/how-to-change-pip-installation-path)

Comment: The accepted answer in the linked question contains incorrect advice in this case