# Importing in Python 3.6.0

Tags: python, import, pip

Can't seem to get imports to work.  I've installed using

```
pip install pyperclip
```

I can can confirm that it was successfully installed:

[image: CMD screenshot]

But then when attempt to confirm in in the Shell:

[image: IDLE screenshot]

Is there another step to importing that I'm just missing?

Comment: Can you do `python -c "import pyperclip"` from the command line?

Comment: Also, A) how do you run Python, and B), what is the output of `python --version`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist also C) what are the contents of `sys.path`

Comment: python --version returns: Python 3.6.0

Comment: I've been running Python from IDLE 3.6 64-bit and CMD.

Comment: as an aside, I would just use tk: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/code/487653/access-the-clipboard-via-tkinter

Comment: >>> print(sys.path)
['', 'C:\\Users\\bbarker\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\Lib\\idlelib', 'C:\\Users\\bbarker\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Users\\bbarker\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\bbarker\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\bbarker\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36', 'C:\\Users\\bbarker\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages']

Comment: And I have used tkinter, but I'm having the issue where no imports will work, not just pyperclip.
When I, python -c "import pyperclip", there is no return message and the shell still does not find the module.

Comment: how did you install python? manually? winpython? anaconda? xy? etc..

Comment: The installer download at [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that pip is installing for the global (all users) version of python, and you're using a version of python installed for only your user *c:\Users\bbarker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36*. You'll want to either use the global install instead *c:\program files (x86)\python36-32* or change your pip defaults as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24175174/3220135).

You'll notice the folder where pip told you where `pyperclip` was installed does not show up in `sys.path`. Therefore python does not know to search there for libraries. Those few file paths you did have in your `sys.path` are automatically generated defaults that are relative to the install directory of the particular instance of python you're currently using. If you use the instance in your *\program files (x86)\* folder, the paths will be relative to that folder instead

**tldr;**

You have 2 instances of python installed, and you're installing libraries to one and using the other.

Comment: @BrendenBarker if this solved your problem, I'd appreciate an upvote or accepted answer..

Comment: My reputation is to low to upvote. Didn't see the check dealio till just now.