# How to change pip package installation directory in Windows 10

Tags: python, pip

Since my C:\ drive is almost full, I need to move my all pip packages to another drive in Windows. Try different methods but didn't work.

I set PIP_TARGET environment variable this changed the installation directory but cannot executes those installed packages. I added to my new directory to PATH variable and that also didn't work.

EDIT:
Currently, I removed PIP_TARGET and pip worked fine but all packages are installed in default location. When I add PIP_TARGET with the target location of **D:\Repo\pip**, new packages are installed in D:\Repo\pip. But when I try to execute them it gives me an error messages saying that package is not installed.

Comment: Have you tried the solution proposed here <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174821/how-to-change-default-install-location-for-pip>?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change default install location for pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174821/how-to-change-default-install-location-for-pip)

Comment: Yes I tried those methods but it didn't work for me