# Changing python pip defualt install directory

Tags: python, package-management

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174821/how-to-change-default-install-location-for-pip) guide to change my default install directory:

**~/.pip/pip.conf**:

```
[global]
target=~/.python-global
```

So that `pip` does not interfere with `pacman`. However, I need to be able to separate python2 and python3. So is there a way to get `pip2` to point to `~/.python-global/python2` and `pip3` to point to `~/.python-global/python3`?

Comment: Personally, I would recommend you use virtualenv or conda to manage your python2 or python3 environments. This seems like an XY problem. When you activate environments using those tools you will have pip point to a new path. If you want further details I can write an answer.

Comment: exactly as mentioned above, that is what venv is for. can also use pipenv.