# pip points to wrong version of python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

How to make **pip** point to **python 2** instead of **python 3** (as it normally should be)?

I want to install a package that is compatible only with **python 2** and I use the **pip** command but it installs the package for **python 3**.

```
[root@q~]# python -V
Python 2.7.5
[root@q~]# python3 -V
Python 3.4.9
[root@q~]# pip -V
pip 19.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip (python 3.4)
[root@q~]# pip3 -V
pip 19.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip (python 3.4)

[root@q~]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

[root@q~]# whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python3.4m /usr/bin/python3.4-config /usr/bin/python3.4m-config /usr/bin/python3.4m-x86_64-config /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/lib/python3.4 /usr/lib64/python2.7 /usr/lib64/python3.4 /etc/python /usr/include/python2.7 /usr/include/python3.4m /opt/borg-env/bin/python /opt/borg-env/bin/python3.4 /usr/share/man/man1/python.1.gz
[root@q~]# whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.4 /usr/bin/python3.4m /usr/bin/python3.4-config /usr/bin/python3.4m-config /usr/bin/python3.4m-x86_64-config /usr/lib/python3.4 /usr/lib64/python3.4 /usr/include/python3.4m /opt/borg-env/bin/python3 /opt/borg-env/bin/python3.4 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz

[root@q~]# whereis pip
pip: /usr/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip3.4 /opt/borg-env/bin/pip /opt/borg-env/bin/pip3.4
[root@q~]# whereis pip3
pip3: /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip3.4 /opt/borg-env/bin/pip3 /opt/borg-env/bin/pip3.4
```

Comment: Can you add the output of the following commands?
`echo $PATH`
`where python`
`where python3`
`where pip`
`where pip3`

Comment: Alternatively, use `python2 -m pip <command>`. Though this may not work for your Python 2 version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change default install location for pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174821/how-to-change-default-install-location-for-pip)

Comment: @00 does not work

Comment: Yeah, was afraid so. Your Python 2 and Python 3 versions are rather old.

Comment: If you have found a package that only supports Python2, then it is probably abandoned, by the way

Comment: @00 yes there is pip

Comment: Do you have a file called `/usr/bin/pip2.7` or `/usr/bin/pip2`?

Comment: @00 pip and /usr/bin/pip is the same thing. both point to python3.

Comment: @gkpln3 no. i only have pip, pip3, pip3.4

Comment: Have you checked with your package manager? There may be a `python-pip` or `python2-pip` package that you can (re)install.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have Python < 2.7.9, then you must [install Pip manually](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

Remove `pip` with `sudo mv /usr/bin/pip /usr/bin/pip.BAK`

Then

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

[Depending on your OS](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-linux-tools/#installing-pip-setuptools-wheel-with-linux-package-managers), then using its package manager may also work

---

Note that Python2 is EOL by the end of the year, so you should find a different library or update it

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you do not have python-pip installed for python2.

Try running this:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

Or this:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

You can also try this if you are on debian:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```