# Wrong install location with pypi packaging for binary and script file

Tags: python, pip, pypi, twine

my `setup.py` file looks like

```
$ cat setup.py 
from setuptools import setup
 
setup(
     name='user1-hello-world',
     version='0.20', 
     scripts=['user1-hello-world'] ,
     data_files=[('/usr/sbin/',['user1-bin2'])]
)
```

I have 1 python script (user1-hello-world) and 1 elf binary file(user1-bin2)

```
$ ls
user1-hello-world user1-bin2 setup.py
```

build and uploading using twine like:

```
 python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
 python3 -m twine upload --repository testpypi dist/*
```

After uploading the files to test.pypi.org. Installing via pip show the files under home dir.

```
/home/user/.local/bin/user1-hello-world
/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/user1_hello_world-0.20.dist-info/*
/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/usr/sbin/user1-bin2
```

I was hoping to install `user1-bin2` under `/usr/sbin` like `/usr/sbin/user1-bin2`. How to achieve this? thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

First, [set the install location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24175174/12846952) by editing $HOME/.pip/pip.conf to

```
[global]
target=usr/sbin
```

or just using `--target usr/sbin`

Then, because the usr/sbin folder requires root rights, don't forget to add a sudo (on linux):

```
sudo pip install your-package
```

Comment: thanks! I think above suggestion is similar to  `pip install --target /some/path` . I'm looking for solution with `setup.py` file. I read `data_files` options should work but in my case it didnt :(

Comment: @webminal.org Ah, I think --target works the same as doing it in the config file. So you want your package to be auto-installed in this special folder?

Comment: Yes, I want `user1-bin2` to be present at `/usr/sbin/user1-bin2`

Comment: Interesting when I install using `pip` its placed on `/usr/sbin/user1-bin2` but I get this location `/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/usr/sbin/user1-bin2` while using pip3.

Comment: @webminal.org I guess its not possible to force the install location as a package creaator, because the user should be able to decide on their own.