# How to use upgraded pip from site-packages?

Tags: python, pip

When I run `pip --version` it returns the default path `/usr/local/apps/python-3.8.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip`. However, when I run `pip install --upgrade pip` it installs the new pip to `/home/username/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`, but the `pip` command still uses the old path ie: system default. I am on a university computing cluster and I don't have root access. Which settings should I modify to ensure that the `pip` command uses the upgraded pip from the local folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably be using a virtual environment to avoid any locally installed `pip`.

```
python3 -mvenv myvenv
```

will install `pip` to `myvenv/bin/`. You can then run `myvenv/venv/pip install --upgrade pip`, and it will perform the upgrade in your virtual environment. (You can also activate the virtual environment with `. ./myvenv/bin/activate`, after which `./myvenv/bin` will be at the front of your search path for the rest of the shell session, allowing you to just run `pip` as before.)

Comment: still having the same issue, `which pip` returns `myenv/bin/pip` but `pip --version` still points to `/usr/local/apps/python-3.8.3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip`

Answer (score 1):

According to [How to change default install location for pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174821/how-to-change-default-install-location-for-pip)

You can set the following environment variable:

> PIP_TARGET=/path/to/pip/dir

Answer provided by @chepner is better as you can isolate your virtual environments. One installation won't overwrite another one when you upgrade and can set to specific versions.

Comment: won't this specify where the libraries are being installed by pip. I want to change the version of `pip` itself which is used. Specifically, the pip version installed in `.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages`