# How to correct wrong pip path in venv?

Tags: python, python-venv

I have a Flask app that with and using venv for my virtual environment. For some reason, `which pip` has suddenly stopped installing packages in `venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages`, but to a completely different repository on my system. How do I redirect pip to install packages to the correct path in venv?

Comment: use `path/to/venv/bin/python -m pip install ...` https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `pip` as a stand alone command in terminal, i suggest you to use `python -m pip` instead, here python will be assoicated with the project (in case of Virtual environment) or whole system level (in case docker single app ). This will keep track and tell the system to run all package/module related to python interpreter assoicated with the project only

Answer (score -1):

You can use the -t flag provided by the pip install command.

```
pip install <package_name> -t <full_location_path>
```

Comment: Would suggest looking at this link if you want to set a permanent path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24174821/how-to-change-default-install-location-for-pip